# C# & ASP.Net - determine linq query generation time

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I'd like to detemine the amount of time it takes for my ASP.Net program to generate certain sql queries using linq.... note - I want the query generation time, not the query execution time. Is this possible, or even feasable (if its usually fast)?

My website has some heavy traffic and I want to cover all of my bases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Redgate ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm) is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Stopwatch + CompiledQuery.Compile ?